# How can i ignore dupkey with sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus, ksh, on-duplicate-key

I want to write a sql plus error for when the oracle find a record, or more records, that already exist and just ignore it/them. This is a example:

```
sqlError=`egrep "ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ${FILE_SPOOL_DAT} | awk '{print $0}';`   
if test ! -f ${FILE_SPOOL_DAT}
then
   echo "Error request " >> ${FILE_SPOOL_DAT}
else
   if [ ! "$sqlError" = "" ] #controls if the variable $sqlError contains a value different from spaces, i think this is the point to change
   then
      echo "Error $sqlError" >> ${FILE_SPOOL_DAT} 
   fi
fi
```

In this example sqlplus controls if the variable `$sqlError` contains a value different from spaces. How can i change this condition put the `DUPKEY` error? Thanks

Comment: What you've written has nothing to do with SQL*Plus... what are you doing prior to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 11g, the [`IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF30052) hint can help.

```
SQL> create table table1(a number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table1 values(1);
insert into table1 values(1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (JHELLER.SYS_C00810741) violated


SQL> insert /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(table1(a))*/ into table1 values(1);

0 rows created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, that's dangerous! If Oracle finds one or more records that already exists, it will normally rollback the transaction. Suppressing the relevant error messages is way to late.

A much better place is to instruct Oracle to ignore duplicate records directly during the `INSERT`, for instance by using the `MERGE` command:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218

Comment: Oracle will _not_ rollback the transaction if they are separate inserts...as there's no information on what's actually happening this statement is completely unsubstantiated. Equally, MERGE will not ignore duplicates, it will raise an error saying that it's unable to get a stable set of rows...

Comment: @Ben OP greps the output of a `SPOOL`, so it's fairly safe to assume that he uses SQL*Plus and most likly that the script has finished. So what happened to the transaction? Which INSERTS went trough, which were rejected? This is not a good way to solve the problem, is it? Likewise MERGE will of course not detect duplicate records in the target table, but can be instructed how to react in case an incoming record is a duplicate of an existing one...

Comment: So guys wich is the best way?

Comment: Can you show us some of your statements that find records that already exist?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a duplicate key error it really means you have violated a constraint set on a table.
Assuming whoever designed the table understood the data model, what you want to do is a BAD idea.
If it is a bad design, change the table's metadata by removing the constraint.

The MERGE command may let you work around it, which I doubt,  but with the subsequent data mess left behind I do not believe it is worth the risk.

If you are just playing, remove the constraint anyway.  I don't know how your table is set up,
but you will probably have to `ALTER` or `DROP` and `CREATE`  an index, or `ALTER` the table.

If this is development for production and thus paid work, don't try to get around the constraint without talking to the person(s) who designed the table to start with.

Comment: Do you think unix way isn't a good idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: The problem is NOT the operating system.  The ways to resolve the problem: do not insert duplicates;  change the constraint/index; get some help from colleagues on how they deal with this.  Your current way will never work - you have to change what you think about the problem.

Comment: oh thanks, i'm new in unix and oracle sorry.. my boss tells me to use sql code but i don't know how it works and if it is the right way :(